# how to find list of addins in a word application

Tags: c#, vsto, add-in

I've created an office:word add-in using visual studio tools for office (VSTO).
I've modified the loadehavior of the add-in to '0' to stop its auto load behavior.

My requirement is to start an word document from a c# application and enable the add-in only for this word instance.

```
Using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

{
  Word.Application wordApp;

  //Instantiate a word application
  wordApp = new Word.Application();
  wordApp.visible = true;

  // Open a document
  wordApp.Documents.Open(ref wordFile, ref Missing.value, ..... etc );  

  foreach (Word.AddIns addins in wordApp.Application.AddIns)
       MessageBox.Show(addins.ToString());
}
```

for loop throws exception:

```
Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.AddIn'
```

*** how to get/store/iterate list of addins/COMaddins ***

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I found solution to my problem:

```
// This will return all the word addins
Microsoft.Office.Core.COMAddIns comAddins = wordApp.COMAddIns;

// Iterate through all the addins 
for(Microsoft.Office.Core.COMAddIns addins in wordApp.COMAddIns)
     MessageBox.Show(addin.Description);
```

Answer (score 0):

As all of us know application level add-ins are applicable for all the instances of the particular application. I succeeded in enabling application level add-in for only particular instance of the application for Office 2007 - Word and Excel. For example, if I start a word instance from a c# application my application level add-in(custom ribbon functionality) would apply only to that instance, behavior of all other instances that are started manually would be normal.

Every application level add-in registers itself in the registry. So every instance of the application would try to load the add-in. So, the main work around lies in loading the ribbon.

At the run time you have to decide if to load the custom ribbon or the basic ribbon.

For this,
->create a process specific environment variable in the c# application where you would instantiate your office application (word/excel).

```
System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("MyVar", "1", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
```

->check for the variable in the ribbon class of your add-in.
Load custom ribbon if the variable exists and basic ribbon if not.

```
public string GetCustomUI(string ribbonID)
{
   if (System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MyVar", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process) == "1")
   {
        return GetResourceText("ExcelAddIn.ExcelRibbon.xml");
   }
   else
   {
        return GetResourceText("ExcelAddIn.BasicRibbon.xml");
   }
}
```

You are almost done!. But windows does not let you maintain two instances (.exes) of word/excel at a time. Because of which each word/excel instance will open from same .EXE and your add-in will be applied to all the instances. So, separate each instance (.exe) of the word/excel.

There is registry hack to achieve this:
In the key,

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\shell\Open\Command
```

append "%1" to the default key value and rename the command key.
In the key,

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\shell\Open
```

rename the ddeexec key.

Regards,